# AFNetworking JSONRequestSerializer POST requestWithMethod Newb Example

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I'm trying to do a JSON POST request (to create a new user) from my iOS app to a cloud back-end REST API using AFNetworking. In my view controller, I'm doing,

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSString *URLString = API_BASE_URL;
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"userName": self.userNameTextField.text,
                             @"password": self.passwordTextField.text};

manager.requestSerializer = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];
```

I've reviewed [the docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/), this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962230/parse-json-response-with-afnetworking), and this [R.Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial) tutorial, but my Frankenstein-ing skills are running out.

The compiler complains about

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'AFHTTPRequestSerializer<AFURLRequestSerialization> *' from 'NSMutableURLRequest *'
```

Has anyone got a pointer to a working example of this or guidance on what might be wrong with my code.

Specifically, how do I initiate the action with a callback?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"userName": username, @"password": password};
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; // if response JSON format
[manager POST:@"http://asd.com/login.php" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

Treat `responseObject` as `NSDictionary`.