# I have try to display data base on status

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, logic

I have got json response and i have to display only those data which status = 1  so how can i do this please help me

my response is

```
JSON: (
        {
        name = "Kate Bell";
        phone = "(555) 564-8583";
        status = 0;
    },
        {
        name = "Daniel Higgins";
        phone = "(408) 555-5270";
        status = 0;
    },
        {
        name = "John Appleseed";
        phone = "888-555-5512";
        status = 0;
    },
        {
        name = "Anna Haro";
        phone = "<null>";
        status = 1;
    },
        {
        name = "Hank Zakroff";
        phone = "<null>";
        status = 1;
    },
 }
```

Comment: can you show your tried code, it is easy to resolve , at the same where you want to show this data based on this condition

Comment: i don't have any idea about how to do this

Comment: Where you get that json, from url?

Comment: yes i get this json from url

Comment: sorry, SO isn't a 'write my code for me' kind-of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with that assumption, your JSON  response start with array

If you really need the string of the JSON, it's available by looking at `operation.responseString`.

I take the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962230/parse-json-response-with-afnetworking)

`responseObject` is either an NSArray or NSDictionary.  You can check at runtime using `isKindOfClass:`:

```
if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSArray *responseArray = responseObject;
    /* do something with responseArray */
     NSPredicate *predi = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = 1"]; 
NSArray *newarray = [responseArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predi];


} else if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *responseDict = responseObject;
    /* do something with responseDict */

     NSArray *responseArray = responseDict[@"yourrootKeyname"];

     NSPredicate *predi = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = 1"]; 
NSArray *newarray = [responseArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predi];
}
```

Comment: it display the null array

Comment: can u update ur question..

Comment: canyou update  the code

Comment: are you got the result or not

Comment: yes i sort out the problem

Comment: can you explain what you did  and what i made in wrong

Answer (score 1):

use predicate to get filtered array with status 1

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = %d", 1]; 
NSArray *arrFilter = [YourWholeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"array with status 1 ->%@",arrFilter);
```